# Error installing models with python3 on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, model

New to coding. I'm building an app that uses the below for server.py to engage a simple html with javascript and a database. When I run the flask app I get the below:

**Error**:

> from models import RequestType, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'?

**On the** **Code Snippet:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from models import RequestType
```

Have been trying to install models for the last half hour with no success...can you help me troubleshoot. I'm using python3 and pip install models, pip install pymodels, and more to no avail. **Can you help me figure this out?**

**The Error on  pip install pymodels**

```
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python: no such file or directory
Collecting pymodels
  Using cached pymodels-0.18.3.tar.gz (45 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/cy/3kv168z56g1bbb5l08qk4n2r0000gn/T/pip-install-jp3s5vpr/pymodels_f32dd5006c6d4648aa749375111e0730/setup.py", line 25, in <module>
          import pymodels
        File "/private/var/folders/cy/3kv168z56g1bbb5l08qk4n2r0000gn/T/pip-install-jp3s5vpr/pymodels_f32dd5006c6d4648aa749375111e0730/pymodels/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
          from base import *
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: How did you install Python on your Mac?

Comment: I'm not sure I set any of this up properly to be honest:

Python
- downloaded from the website (version 3.11)
- installed in .bash_profile with export `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$PATH"`
- also installed in .zshrc with export `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$PATH"export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

I'm not sure I follow how to know where to put it and if it being in multiple places is problematic as there were different steps online.

Comment: I also have it in .zshrc as export `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$PATH"export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

`pymodels` has renamed to `doqu`

Try to install the package using `pip install doqu` instead

I can see that OP wants to create data models, I suggest using `sqlalchemy` as its a well maintained library, it has lots more [tutorials](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/) which is more friendly for beginners. It is also compatible with `Flask`